# C# HttpSelfHostServer Routes.MapHttpRoute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have problem with the following routes:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name:"Logs-Watcher-File", 
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{watcher}/{id}", 
    defaults: new { controller = "Logs", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Logs-Index", 
    routeTemplate: "{controller}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Logs" }
    );
```

this is the controller:

```
public class LogsController : ApiController {
    public HttpResponseMessage GetIndex() {

    }

    public HttpResponseMessage GetWatcher(string watcher) {
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Getlogfile(string watcher, string id) {
    }
}
```

if i open `http://locahost:*myport*/Logs` then GetIndex() is called --> **OK**

if i open `http://locahost:*myport*/Logs/WatcherName` then GetWatcher(string watcher) is called with the correct **watcher** parameter --> **OK**

(WatcherName is dynamicly created/loaded so it can be any name)

**and here is the problem:**
if i open `http://locahost:*myport*/Logs/WatcherName/123` then GetIndex() is called --> **NOK**

Any idea why `Getlogfile(string watcher, string id)` doesn't match?

tried any posible combinations (even defined {action} and used the [ActionName("logfile")]) and also changed the parameter from **string id** to **int id** without success

any help would be appreciated

**Edit (fixed):**
the problem was an other route i had as first route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Ui", "{controller}/{path}/{fileName}", new { controller = "Ui" });
```

Fixed it replacing `{controller}` with the corresponding prefix `Logs` or `Ui`

have fun guys

Comment: You might as well just post the answer to your own question.